# Regex for Dublin Postal Codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I need to build a Regex query for Dublin postal codes, to validate forms in a Rails app.

Dublin Post Codes range from 1-22, and users are putting in inputs that include:

"Dublin 22"
"dublin 22"
"dublin22"
"Dublin22"
"D2"
"d2"
"D 2"
"d 2"
"2"

In Ruby, I've started to write long validator methods to cover some of these. I wonder if there's a simpler solution in Regex.

```
  def formatted_postal_code
    # used to produce postal code in the format "Dublin 2"  
    if self.postal_code_is_i? &&  self.postal_code.to_i.between?(1, 22)
      # check if postal code is an integer  
      self.postal_code = "Dublin " + self.postal_code
    elsif
    else
      # capitalize postal code
      self.postal_code.capitalize  
    end
  end

  def postal_code_is_i?
    /\A[-+]?\d+\z/ === self.postal_code
  end
```

Any help or advice are appreciated.

Comment: Where you say, "inputs that include:", are you providing examples or is that the complete range of possibilities? You really need to provide the latter. "Dublin <extra spaces> 22"? "Dublin 02"? "D-22"? "DUBlin 22"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
test = "dublin 22"

p "true" if test =~ /^d?(ublin)?(\s)?22?$/i
```